# mapstruct - Use mapper from another package

Tags: java, mapstruct

I use mapstruct in my projects and it works fine for the straight forward way (All mapper in one package).
Now I have the requirement to move one mapper to another package, but this doesn't work well.

working package structure (1):

```
de.zinnchen
├── dto
│   └── Car.java
├── entity
│   └── CarEntity.java
└── mapper
    └── a
        ├── CarMapper.java
        └── DateMapper.java
```

NOT working package structure (2):

```
de.zinnchen
├── dto
│   └── Car.java
├── entity
│   └── CarEntity.java
└── mapper
    ├── a
    │   └── CarMapper.java
    └── b
        └── DateMapper.java
```

my java files:

```
package de.zinnchen.dto;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class Car {

  private String manufacturer;
  private String model;
  private String color;
  private LocalDateTime productionDate;
...
```

```
package de.zinnchen.entity;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class CarEntity {
  private String manufacturer;
  private String model;
  private String color;
  private Instant productionDate;
...
```

```
package de.zinnchen.mapper.a;

import de.zinnchen.dto.Car;
import de.zinnchen.entity.CarEntity;
import de.zinnchen.mapper.b.DateMapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;

@Mapper(
    uses = DateMapper.class
)
public interface CarMapper {


  Car asDto(CarEntity entity);

  CarEntity asEntity(Car car);

}
```

```
package de.zinnchen.mapper.b;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

public class DateMapper {

  LocalDateTime instantToLocalDateTime(Instant instant) {
    return instant
        .atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"))
        .toLocalDateTime();
  }

  Instant LocalDateTimeToInstant(LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
    return localDateTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
  }
}
```

Once I try to compile the variant with mappers in different packages I get the following error message:
Can't map property "Instant productionDate" to "LocalDateTime productionDate". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "LocalDateTime map(Instant value)".

Can you please help me for solving this problem?

**Edit**
Resulting CarMapperImpl.java of package structure 1:

```
package de.zinnchen.mapper.a;

import de.zinnchen.dto.Car;
import de.zinnchen.entity.CarEntity;
import javax.annotation.processing.Generated;

@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2021-01-06T09:36:43+0100",
    comments = "version: 1.4.1.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 11.0.9.1 (AdoptOpenJDK)"
)
public class CarMapperImpl implements CarMapper {

    private final DateMapper dateMapper = new DateMapper();

    @Override
    public Car asDto(CarEntity entity) {
        if ( entity == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Car car = new Car();

        car.setManufacturer( entity.getManufacturer() );
        car.setModel( entity.getModel() );
        car.setColor( entity.getColor() );
        car.setProductionDate( dateMapper.instantToLocalDateTime( entity.getProductionDate() ) );

        return car;
    }

    @Override
    public CarEntity asEntity(Car car) {
        if ( car == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        CarEntity carEntity = new CarEntity();

        carEntity.setManufacturer( car.getManufacturer() );
        carEntity.setModel( car.getModel() );
        carEntity.setColor( car.getColor() );
        carEntity.setProductionDate( dateMapper.LocalDateTimeToInstant( car.getProductionDate() ) );

        return carEntity;
    }
}
```

Comment: so you mean on the first package structure, everything works fine but on the second one only the error occurs?

Comment: Yes, on first package structure everything works fine. I added the resulting CarMapperImpl.java file for package structure 1 to my original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it isn't working is due to the fact that the methods in the `DateMapper` are package protected and are not available from other packages.

So if you add `public` to the methods then it will work.